# SBS 2011: change display language for end user of the internal website?

Tags: windows-sbs, windows-sbs-2011

I like to manage the SBS 2011 in English, but the clients require a different language for viewing the internal website, as well as OWA. I've been searching on the web, but according to the following release document, SBS 2011 doesn't support language packs:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491249.aspx

I've also found a language pack for SharePoint 2010:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262108.aspx

but it looks like it only changes the display language of the SharePoint part of the internal website. I wonder if there is any workaround for this problem. Can someone please shed a light on this? If the answer is a definite NO, I'll go ahead reinstall SBS in another language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible in SBS. Windows SBS 2011 Standard does not support the use of language interface packs (LIP) or multilingual user interface (MUI) packs.

You will have to reinstall it in the appropriate language.

Comment: Thanks for the NO answer, at least it'll save me hours of googling, :-).

Comment: Your answer is more than 5 1/2 years old. Can it be the situation changed? Now there is an option to install a language file but I don't find any English language package which I could provide there. Do you have more information?

Comment: @AlBundy: Just had a look on out Partner Portal and I don't see any downloads like that, so I'm afraid not.